# OAuth 2.0 Authentication and Authorization

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a web service written in node.js and I have a server that is running MongoDB, my question is, how can I implement OAuth 2.0 when according to [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) in my case, the resource owner, the resource server and the authorization server are the same? i.e. I want to use OAuth to authenticate and authorize users that are in my own database and not from other resource owners(like facebook or twitter).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question -- implementing oauth is quite complex if you're looking to roll your own solution.

If I were you I'd look into using a library like [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) or [Stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/) to help offload this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed generic information about what developers have to do to implement [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) in [Authlete Definitive Guide](https://www.authlete.com/authlete_definitive_guide.html) and [Authlete Blog](http://blog.authlete.com/). Although the documents refer to a specific solution ([Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/)), the contents will serve as a useful reference for developers who dare to implement their own OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect servers.